# bash string manipulation - Display the value, not the variable name

Tags: string, bash, sed

I'm writing a script to process inbound data files. The inbound file names all follow the same pattern:

```
word1_word2_word3_YYYYMMDD.txt
```

My script takes the name of the inbound file, strips the file extension, strips out the date, replaces all underscores with spaces and appends the resulting string to each line in the original file. I can succesfully create the desired string and have assigned it to a variable "STR"

The last step is to append the value of $STR to each line in the file  so that the data lines within the file  end up looking like this:

```
casenumber1"|"word1 word2 word3  
casenumber2"|"word1 word2 word3  
casenumber3"|"word1 word2 word3
```

My problem is that for the life of me I cannot get bash to display the variable value, it always displays the variable name.

This is the line I use to create the string needed from the file name:

```
STR=`echo $DATAFILENAME | cut -d '.' -f 1 | sed 's/[0-9]*//g'|sed 's/_/ /g' | sed  's/[[:blank:]]*$//'`
```

I'm trying to use a typical sed replace command:

```
sed 's/$/`echo "$STR"`/g' inputfile > outputfile
```

But keep getting the variable name instead of the variable value:

example output:

```
1000056|$"STR"  
1000057|$"STR"  
...
```

desired output:

```
1000056|Closed With Notification  
1000057|Closed With Notification
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks, Vic

Comment: Somewhere in all this text is, I suspect, a fairly simple question. Could you trim it down a bit? For example, the first paragraph is entirely unnecessary.

Comment: To add to @chepner's comment: People are much more likely to help you if you whittle this down to a concise problem description, with representative sample input and desired output. See [MCVE (Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: and consider editing your Q to include small set of sample input data, and the required format as output (from the same input). Doing this will save you paragraphs of description. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Will do.

Comment: pluse uno for improving your question.

Answer (score 2):

The gist of your question is that you need to add a string to a file using sed and the value of that string is contained in a variable, which you call "a", as we read in the final list.

Then you need use this combination, which is missing from your list above:

```
sed "s/$/| $a/g"  $DATAFILE > datfile99
```

The problem is that the single quotes around your command prevent the interpolation of the variable $a.

If you wrap the command in double quotes the whole string will be passed to *sed* **after** that the shell replaces $a to its current value.

Comment: Well explained; it may be worth adding that, generally, `\$` should be used inside double-quoted shell strings to safely preserve `$` as a literal to pass to the target command; in the case at hand it happens not to be needed,  because `$` is followed by `/`, which cannot be mistaken for a variable reference, but in other cases it may.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing your `'` with `"` this will tell your shell to substitute any shell variables

sed -i "s/$/`echo $STR`/g"

Note `-i` option will make actual changes to your file, hence it is wise to backup.

EDIT: instead of using this

```
STR=`echo $DATAFILENAME | cut -d '.' -f 1 | sed 's/[0-9]*//g'|sed 's/_/ /g' | sed  's/[[:blank:]]*$//'`
```

You can try this

```
sed -i -r "s/(.*)[.][a-zA-Z]+$/\\1/g;s/[._]/ /g" <<< "$DATAFILENAME"
```